# Can iterating over DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles throw an exception?

Tags: c#, exception, io

Calling `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles` can throw an exception such as `DirectoryNotFoundException`. Can this only happen when I fetch the `IEnumerable` object, or also while iterating over the files (i.e. when `foreach` calls `IEnumerator<FileInfo>.MoveNext`)?

In other words, is the following code safe?

```
 IEnumerable<FileInfo> fileInfos;
 try
 {
     fileInfos = directoryInfo.EnumerateFiles();
 }
 catch // snip
 {
    // snip
 }

 foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in fileInfos)
 {
     // Do something
 }
```

Or do I need to put the foreach part into a try block, too (which becomes quite nasty if I want to `yield return` something, which is not allowed in a try block)?

Assuming the enumerator does not throw an exception, what happens when the directory is being deleted while iterating over the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this API can throw an exception on both the `EnumerateFiles` / `EnumerateDirectories` call **and** the `MoveNext` call. In either case, once an exception has been thrown, you cannot continue using that enumerator.

It's not just `DirectoryNotFoundException`; it can also throw `UnauthorizedAccessException`, `PathTooLongException` and others.

This has been [reported to Microsoft](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/512171/directory-enumeratedirectory-etc-unusable-due-to-frequent-unauthorizedaccessexceptions-even-runas-administrator), but there's no news on a fix. In the meantime, there's an [alternative API on CodePlex](http://rwtools.codeplex.com/), or a [different approach on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098011/directory-enumeratefiles-unauthorizedaccessexception).