# BackgroundWorker calling Directory.EnumerateFiles completes before enumeration finishes

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, .net

A trivial issue it seems.

I have the following code snippet. It seems that the completed event fires before EnumerateFiles actually finishes. For example, if the tb_source.Text ... which is a path like `C:\users\<user>\desktop` is set to a folder with say a hundred or so items, all works and `reference.throttler_numer_of_files` is correctly populated.

It looks though that if I set that to say, `C:\users\<user>` it never gets a chance to find everything before moving on to the completed event. Perhaps it encounters an exception when trying to count the files?

Suggesetions?

```
// count number of files within source directory (and within subdirectories)
BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(
    delegate(object o, DoWorkEventArgs args)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000); // give the current UI a moment to load
        reference.throttler_number_of_files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(tb_source.Text, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
    }
);

bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(
    delegate(object o, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        // success, clear to launch!
        form_throttler_copy throttler_copy = new form_throttler_copy();
        throttler_copy.Show();
        this.Dispose();
    }
);

label_status.Text = "Creating manifest of files... please wait";
picturebox_loading.Visible = true;

bw.RunWorkerAsync();
```

Comment: Inspect the error property http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.componentmodel.runworkercompletedeventargs(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Any time you have to call `Thread.Sleep` to synchronize events, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that there was an exception (access denied) error during EnumerateFiles. I'm able to catch the exception but now I must determine a good way I can continue the enumeration, making it move on to the next file/directory.

Edit - for future reference, details here were helpful on how to do the above:
[Directory.EnumerateFiles => UnauthorizedAccessException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098011/directory-enumeratefiles-unauthorizedaccessexception)