# Continue Foreach Loop On Error

Tags: c#, foreach

I want to continue my code when error comes up , but i dont know how ...

here's my code :

```
foreach(string path in Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
{
    Console.WriteLine(path);
}
```

And the error comes on `foreach(string path in Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)` and i don't know how to continue this loop

and the error :

> Unauthorized access

And even i run my code as Administrator this error comes up again

Thanks,

Comment: change access settings of your c:\

Comment: I want to work on other computers ...too

Comment: I'm a bit confused at your question. Do you want permission so your code works on every directory or do you want your code to skip a directory it doesn't have permission to?

Comment: I want to skip that directory and go to the next...

Comment: `try-catch` block will allow your app to continue despite error

Comment: for starters your foreach loop is incorrect.. you are missing a `)` at the end

Comment: your error is "An exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code" you don't have permission to access all the directories in c drive so you are not even getting inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is to use recursive search and not using `SearchOption.AllDirectories`, but rather `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly`

If you use `SearchOption.AllDirectories`, **one** access violation will break your entire loop even before **any** file/directory is processed. But if you use `SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly`, you only skip what is inaccessible.

Thus, to do it, you can create a method which receives a directory path as input. And in that method, if the input directory have child directory(ies) (see `Directory.GetDirectories(string path)` method, you call the method again for each child directory (recursive call) before you process all the files in the directory. Else, get the files (see `Directory.GetFiles`) in the directory and process them immediately.

Then for the method above, one way is to prevent the code crash when you cannot access certain file/directory is by using `try-catch` block for each child directory reading and file reading. This way, if one file/folder cannot be accessed, your code will still be running, finding the processing the next file/directory.

Alternatively, you can use `Directory.GetAccessControl()` per child directory check to see if you have an access to a `Directory` before hand (this option is rather hard though).

Edit (code added):

Something like this will do:

```
public static List<string> GetAllAccessibleDirectories(string path, string searchPattern) {
    List<string> dirPathList = new List<string>();
    try {
        List<string> childDirPathList = Directory.GetDirectories(path, searchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).ToList(); //use TopDirectoryOnly
        if (childDirPathList == null || childDirPathList.Count <= 0) //this directory has no child
            return null;
        foreach (string childDirPath in childDirPathList) { //foreach child directory, do recursive search
            dirPathList.Add(childDirPath); //add the path
            List<string> grandChildDirPath = GetAllAccessibleDirectories(childDirPath, searchPattern);
            if (grandChildDirPath != null && grandChildDirPath.Count > 0) //this child directory has children and nothing has gone wrong
                dirPathList.AddRange(grandChildDirPath.ToArray()); //add the grandchildren to the list
        }
        return dirPathList; //return the whole list found at this level
    } catch {
        return null; //something has gone wrong, return null
    }
}
```

And to call it, you can do something like this

```
string rootpath = @"C:\DummyRootFolder";
List<string> dirList = GetAllAccessibleDirectories(rootpath, "*.*"); //you get all accessible directories here
```

In the `dirList` you will get all the directories that you search for, and if there is access violation along the way, it will only affects sub-directories search due to the `try-catch` block.

Note that the `rootpath` is excluded in the method. But if you want to add it to the list too, you could simply do

```
dirList.Insert(0, path); //do this after you get dirList
```

There are also more [complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281620/checking-for-directory-and-file-write-permissions-in-net) [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130617/how-do-you-check-for-permissions-to-write-to-a-directory-or-file) [of doing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410127/c-sharp-test-if-user-has-write-access-to-a-folder) this by using `Directory.GetAccessControl` and `PermissionSet`

Hope it may clarify.

Comment: I can't get what is your mean... if its possible , write the code 
Thanks

Comment: Code added according to your request, see if it clarifies what I mean

Comment: Glad that you find it helpful! =) But please note that this code is simple yet not optimal. This is because you only realize that you violate certain directory access control **after** you try to read it. This will impair your performance at some level. So, just in case you need better solution, you might need to use `GetAccessControl` method.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you should look at EnumerateDirectories for performance reasons:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc(v=vs.110).aspx

Also, it appears that this question has already been answered before:

[Directory.EnumerateFiles => UnauthorizedAccessException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098011/directory-enumeratefiles-unauthorizedaccessexception)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
foreach (string path in Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\", "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {

            try { 
                Console.WriteLine(path);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to access directories in path: " + path);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You don't want to catch on any kind of exception. You probably want to be as explicit as possible with catching exceptions (in this case).

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc I disagree in this case given that the original poster said "I want to continue my code when error comes up , but i dont know how"  He didn't say he wanted to continue for some errors but not others, he said for all errors which is exactly what my code does.