# How to ignore Junction Points in Documents folder when using IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories

Tags: .net, vb.net, windows, directory, filesystems

```
    Dim dirs As List(Of String)
    dirs = New List(Of String)(IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
```

The following code works fine for the most part but always fails on the c:\users\documents folder because of Junction points.

I get the following exception and stack trace.

Is there a way to exclude junction points and use EnumerateDirectories or will have to write code to manually get the directory names and ignore/handle junction points?

**Exception:**
{"Access to the path 'C:\Users\jkfredri\Documents\My Music' is denied."}

**Stack Trace:**
"   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)" & vbCrLf & "   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.AddSearchableDirsToStack(SearchData localSearchData)" & vbCrLf & "   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()" & vbCrLf & "   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)" & vbCrLf & "   at BUDWindows.BUD.FileSystem.Directory.GetDirectoriesList(String path) in C:\Users\\Visual Studio\Projects\Desktop Applications\BUDWindows\Classes\FileSystemManager.vb:line 292"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Directory.EnumerateFiles => UnauthorizedAccessException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098011/directory-enumeratefiles-unauthorizedaccessexception)

Comment: As per meta, [Possible duplicate question in another (programming) language](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319542/1070452) a different language makes it not a dupe.  Its pretty easy to convert but not for everyone.  The link may help a poster, but they *are* different languages and tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `FileAttribute` which indicates if it is a `ReparsePoint` entry.  To get at it, you need a `DirectoryInfo` object.  Since each one needs to be tested, you could use `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateDirectories()` to get a list of them rather than creating them one by one from the names you are getting.

Then, if you just want the name, `Select` that after the `ReparsePoint`s have been excluded.  Extension methods can do most of the work:

```
Dim dInfo = New DirectoryInfo(dPath)
Dim DirNames = dInfo.EnumerateDirectories("*.*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).
                Where(Function(q) IsReparse(q) = False).
                Select(Function(q) q.FullName).
                ToList()

For Each s As String In DirNames.ToArray()
    DirNames.AddRange(Directory.
                        EnumerateDirectories(s, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
Next
```

Then, a helper method:

```
Private Function IsReparse(d As DirectoryInfo) As Boolean
    Return ((d.Attributes And FileAttributes.ReparsePoint) = FileAttributes.ReparsePoint)
End Function
```

This gets the top level folder names where the `Reparse` attribute is false, then iterates those to get sub folder names.  The premise is that the `Reparse` folders will be at the top level only.  Then with that out of the way, it just adds the sub folders to the list.

Apparently, even testing for the `ReparsePoint` first doesnt prevent it from looking for sub folders in them with `SearchOption.AllDirectories`.

You could put the `FileAttributes` test in the WHERE method, but depending on what you are doing, you may find you also want to skip ones with the `System` attribute.

Comment: This worked for me.  Thanks Plutonix I really appreciate your help.