# VB.Net Anti-Virus Scanner

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to code an Anti-Virus scanner & can get a single file scan to work, but my "Full System scan" doesn't work correctly. Here is the code (for one location to be scanned):

```
Dim hash_type As String
Dim file_name As String
Dim array() As Byte
Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles)
For Each foundFile As FileInfo In dir.GetFiles("*.exe", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    ScanLocation.Items.Add(dir)
    Dim path As String = foundFile.ToString
    txtFilePath.Text = path
    Dim sample As String
    sample = md5_hash(path)
    Dim File As System.IO.StreamReader = System.IO.File.OpenText("C:\Program Files\MalwareBlocker\Signatures.txt")
    Dim File1 As String = File.ReadToEnd()
    File.Close()
    If File1.Contains(sample) Then
        InfectedFiles.Items.Add(sample)
    Else
        'IGNORE
    End If
Next foundFile
```

I would like the scanner to covert each .exe file in directories such as "Program Files", "Roaming" & "Temp" & then check each .exe file MD5 to a text file of signatures.

Comment: You say it doesnt work what do you mean.... be more precice. You know that just signature check isn't a good anti virus?

Comment: Yeah I know I am trying to make a scanner - no Real-time protection, just for cleanup purposes.

Comment: The thing that doesn't work is the process of getting the file locations.

Comment: your only searchin program files (dir) just do a AllDirectories in C:\ with admin rights and should work.

Comment: What should I do to prevent the software trying to access denied areas though? Otherwise an error gets produced.

Comment: And also no that method doesn't work.

Comment: Look at the error: https://ufile.io/mmd7i

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022677/searching-a-drive-with-vb-net

Comment: Make sure you start visual studio in administration while debug

Comment: I am but I keep getting errors that it cannot access files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42742018/vb-net-directory-enumeratefiles-access-to-path-x-is-denied/42775042#42775042